# ChangeDetector Tool in ArcGIS by Bruce Harold

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2

I have downloaded the tool "[ChangeDetector](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=e06a278da4e94d168427f45ef4a8c5b7)." by Bruce Harold for ArcGIS. I´m using arcGIS 10.2. Unfortunately I´m getting all the time some errors:

<'type 'exceptions:unicodeError'> ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf6' in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)

by choosing shape as the only search field I´m getting the following error:

<'type 'exceptions:Runtime:Error'>: Object: CreateObject cannot create geometry from Inputs.

Comment: If it is the tool I have used (please provide a link to it), it can't handle other characters than a-z. If you have any ä, é or other non-English characters in file name, field name or text data in your attribute table, it wont work.

Comment: Here is the link to the [Tool](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=e06a278da4e94d168427f45ef4a8c5b7).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The tool you have downloaded is very useful, I myself have used it several times. However, it cannot handle non-English characters like ä, ö, é, ü etc. These characters can't be in the file name, field names, or in your data. The unicode character for `xf6` in your error message above corresponds to `ö`, so it is likely that this is your problem.

I have created a code to replace those characters which usually appears in my data, in order for me to be able to use *Change detector*. It aint all that pretty, but it gets the work done. I have set it up as a script tool with *Input shapefile* as first parameter, and the field to which you want to do changes as second input. It applies changes to your source data, so make sure you have a backup.

```
# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-
def code(infield):
    data = ''
    for i in infield:
##        print i
        if i == u'\xc4': #Ä
            data = data + 'AE'
        elif i == u'\xe4': #ä
            data = data + 'ae'
        elif i == u'\xc5': #Å
            data = data + 'AA'
        elif i == u'\xe5': #å
            data = data + 'aa'
        elif i == u'\xd6': #Ö
            data = data + 'OE'
        elif i == u'\xf6': #ö
            data = data + 'oe'
        else:
            data = data + i
    return data


shp = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
field = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
##newfield = field + '_U'
##arcpy.AddField_management(shp, newfield, 'TEXT')

prows = arcpy.UpdateCursor(shp)

for row in prows:
    row.field = code(row.getValue(field))
    prows.updateRow(row)
```

Also keep in mind, the download page states that the function is created for 10.1. I doubt there's been such major changes between 10.1 and 10.2 that it would affect the successful completion of the script, but there's still a chance.